# App name availability in PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play

Would like to know how and where in Google Play Store verifies the app name has been used?
I even can create an app called Facebook (in draft mode).
In iTune Connect, it will prompt me that the app name has been used. But not in Play Store.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Play, not programming

Comment: Sorry about that, where can I post this question accordingly?

Comment: id for the application imho is its full-package-name.

Comment: I think you have try add your app identity or your app unique word after Facebook word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think they care about app name, there's a lot of apps with the same name in google play store, but they do by package name. for example com.facebook.katana

Comment: Do you mean the last word will be the app name? In your case would be Katana?

Comment: yes,com.facebook.katana  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana  the id should be unique!

Comment: How about the display name? Is it the one we enter value into Title field during app creation?

Comment: In google play, the same app can have a names for each language..read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html  but the package name should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can create any name in draft mode.

Please check this link. It will explain all
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en

**But, you can't change Package name once you uploaded app on play store.**